# flashDevelop & fla

Tags: flash, flashdevelop

I am just getting into Flash and AS3. I started using Flash Develop.

I am trying to use the code which came along with an Actionscript3 book.

The Sample code has a .fla file along with the as3 file.

I dont see an embed line in the as3. (Is that the only way for the .fla to be included)

When I create an AS3 project in Flash Develop, it creates a bin and src folders. I tried to put the .fla and as3 files to compile but the build failed.

please advice.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flash Develop is an Actionscript Editor supporting several compilers:

- Flash Professional IDE
- Flex SDK Compiler
- mtasc (no need to know what this is)

The **Flash Professional IDE is the only way for you to compile FLA files** to the SWF format. That means you edit your actionscript inside Flash Develop then compile with Flash Professional. Check out the ASCompletion.PathToFlashIDE setting, you can configure the path to Flash Professional there.

To use the Flash IDE as compiler make sure you select "Flash IDE Project" when you create a new project and that you have defined the path to Flash.exe properly.

Comment: Thanks for the instructions. I got it to build and run.

Answer (score 2):

in Flash Develop you cannot use FLA files.

Maybe could be useful for you to read some getting started tutorial with flash develop... http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=AS3

Instead of your FLA file (I suppose that there are not animations, but AS3 only), you can create a Main.as class estending the Sprite into the SRC folder. In this Main.as you can put the AS3 code of your FLA.

To be more specific or provide examples I need more info about your FLA.

Let me know.

Comment: I have gone through the link, you provided and still a little confused. I am trying to compile the code from [link](http://friendsofed.com/downloads/9781430226147/Essential_Guide_To_Flash_Games.zip ) Its a [book](http://www.8bitrocket.com/books/the-essential-guide-to-flash-games/) on flash games. I took the files given in balloons directory and tried to compile it in FlashDevelop.